# SDK Registration Failed. Please check the bundle ID

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I downloaded the latest version of DJI-SDK sample code.

For some reasons I'm getting following note when running the app (in mobile) "SDK Registration Failed. Please check the bundle ID..."

The app key has been created and placed to the AndroidManifest.xml and there is network available. Should the app name be in manifest-file or can it be whatever?

All advises are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Where you created your app key, make sure your Package Name/Bundle Id is set to 'com.dji.sdk.sample' for the sample program.

The package name in Android Studio must match the package name in the DJI app you are trying to use.

[Image of DJI developer app information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ild4P.png)

Answer (score 3):

The value should be taken from your app's build.gradle file.   It appears in the defaultConfig section under the name applicationId.

The SDK documents suggest it's taken from the manifest file but I have found that information to appear to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I also happened to have the same problem before (about 2 hours ago)... and already tried all methods that have been discussed here and in some other posts. In the end, my problem is actually in bundle.gradle(:app) where the 'applicationId' in 'defaultConfig' block is not changed to my app package name yet because I simply copy&paste 100% of the sample gradle without checking it first... tbh, this is my 1st time trying DJI-sdk.